# htaccess - if no cookie, redirect to subfolder

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, redirect, cookies

i want to secure /wp-admin directory from DDOS, so i thought that it would be good idea to block everybody with htaccess who dont have some special cookie (named 'mzgtest' with value 'tak'). if somebody dont have this cookie should be redirected to /wp-admin/login subfolder

i wrote this .htaccess file (i located it in /wp-admin subfolder) rule:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_COOKIE} !mzgtest=tak [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ ./login/ [NC,L]
```

but it dosnt work. it works opposite. when this rule is set:

- if somebody has cookie mzgtest=test, is redirected to /wp-admin/login subfolder
- if somebody doesnt have this cookie, is redirected to /wp-admin/login but browser shows error 500

any idea how it should be written?

Comment: If it works the opposite way to intended then what happens when you remove the `!` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're getting 500 (internal error) because of infinite looping as Apache keeps forwarding to `/admin/login/`. You need to set the cookie if it is not already set:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_COOKIE} !mzgtest=tak [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ login/ [L,CO=mzgtest:tak:%{HTTP_HOST}]
```

Comment: than you but it doesnt solve my problem



what if i dont want to set this cookie for everybody? this will be secret cookie, which i will set in some secret way :)



the method is to prevent from ddos attack on /wp-admin directory. i will set for authorized users this secret cookie and only thos people should be able to login in /wp-admin. others, who dont have cookie should be redirected to this /login directory (or just blocked in another way, i am open for suggestions)

Comment: **Suggestions:** You can detect authorized users based on their IP addresses OR by using HTTP Basic Authentication.

Comment: in this situation i cannot :( too many users, too many ips. also i cannot use basic auth: in /wp-admin are some files which should be available without autorisation